# How to make NetBeans understand the "import" and "export" statements of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, netbeans

Currently, if I have e.g. `import {localeModule, test} from '../qunit';` in a JS file, NetBeans (8.0.2) marks it as an error: "Expected an operand but found import".

Does the latest NetBeans version really don't have support for that statement (doesn't sound credible for such a popular IDE, supposedly one of the best in JavaScript support), or is there some switch I have to change in the settings?

Installing NodeJS plugin didn't help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any solution?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. I don't need to use import often, so I left it at that. Would be glad to hear a solution though.

Comment: Did anything change about that?

Comment: It seems that the new 8.1 Netbeans version still gives the same error (unless I need to turn a switch somewhere).

Answer (score 1):

Ah ha!
The problem is what version of Javascript you have selected. JS6 supports 'import x from y;' syntax.

So for example if you are using the newest generator-angular-fullstack (which tries to show the newest, best practices) and get the import errors just:

In Webstorm: File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript -> Javascript language version, select JS6 vs JS5.x

Problem: I haven't found out how to set the JavaScript compliance version (like Eclipse has for Java) for even NetBeans 8.1 RC2 (yet).

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no support yet as of Netbeans 8.0.2

[ES6 syntax support](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242387)

And found this post

[link to the post](http://dev.topheman.com/why-i-left-netbeans-for-webstorm/)